# ¿Como colocar una pagina web fuera de servicio?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de colocar mi pagina web fuera de servicio, me explico, lo que quiero es que cuando se ingrese cualquier dirección de mi sitio redireccionar a otra pagina en la que estará el anuncio de dice que esta fuera de linea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con esto en el .htaccess de la que estará en mantenimiento

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://otrodominio.com/ [R=301]
```

Comment: Si, esto me funcionó muchas gracias amigo

Comment: ahora si a donde quiero redirigir esta en ese mismo servidor ?

Comment: Puedes crear otra carpeta con su propio .htaccess